# How limit size of file upload but show a meaningful response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload, httppostedfilebase

I added this to my `web.config` file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960"/> <!-- Limit to 40 megabytes -->
```

And when I try to upload something bigger than 40 megabytes, I get this in Firefox:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

  * The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
  * If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  * If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Is there some way to also benefit from this built in file size limitation but actually show a nice error page? Of course I could do this check in the controller but at that point the traffic is already spent because the huge file has reached my server.

```
if (image.ContentLength > 40960) // 'image' is HttpPostedFileBase
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this in your global.asax.cs?

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.TotalBytes > 40960 * 1024)
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write("File uploaded is greater than 40 MB");
    }

}
```